# Drools insert order

Tags: drools

I am trying to set up drools for a question set but the order seems to be random. I have tried using salience but the order is still random.

```
rule "Question Set One"
// First
salience 90
when
then
    QuestionList questionList = new QuestionList();
questionList.add(new Question(Key.FIRST_NAME, "Field", AnswerType.STRING));
questionList.add(q);
QuestionSet questionSet = new QuestionSet("Question Set One", questionList);
insert(questionSet);
end

rule "Ask Your Contact Details"
salience 5
when
then
QuestionList questionList = new QuestionList();
questionList.add(new Question(Key.FIRST_NAME, "First Name", AnswerType.STRING));
 questionList.add(new Question(Key.LAST_NAME, "Last Name", AnswerType.STRING));
 questionList.add(new Question(Key.EMAIL, "Email Address", AnswerType.STRING));
QuestionSet questionSet = new QuestionSet("Contact Details",     questionList);
    insert(questionSet);
end
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is, trying to guess and answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The order of insertions (i.e., an execution of `insert(.)`) depends on the order some right hand sides are executed, viz. their rules are "fired". Without salience, this order depends on circumstances that are difficult to control - and nobody wants to, because it shouldn't matter anyway.

If it *does* matter, one way to control this is salience, as you have it in these rules, although there's no apparent reason why it should matter with these two rules. So, "Question Set One" will be fired first, and "Question Set One" is the first one to be inserted. (You have shown nothing that would indicate otherwise.)

After these two inserts have been made, two `QuestionSet` facts reside in WorkingMemory. There is no concept of order of any kind defined on those facts.

If you need your facts to be in some order, add a property like "rank", assign suitable values (ordinals or whatever), and write your rules accordingly.